# You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_2'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, classification, conv-neural-network, placeholder

I am trying to restore my saved model and make a class prediction from it.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

#paths to saved model
path_to_meta = 'Saved_Models/VGGNet.ckpt.meta'
path_check = 'Saved_Models/VGGNet.ckpt'

#test data
Input_data = np.ones([1,32,32,1], dtype=np.float32)
top_k = 5

#importing models meta
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(path_to_meta)
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
global_step_tensor = graph.get_tensor_by_name('add_8:0')

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 32, 32, 1))
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)       # for fully-connected layers
keep_prob_conv = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)  # for convolutional layers

tensor = tf.math.top_k(tf.nn.softmax(global_step_tensor), k=top_k)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # To initialize values with saved data
    saver.restore(sess, path_check)
    y_prob, y_pred = sess.run(tensor, feed_dict={x:Input_data, keep_prob:1.0, keep_prob_conv:1.0})
```

Then I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1356, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)

  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1341, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)

  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1429, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)

InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_2' with dtype float
     [[{{node Placeholder_2}}]]
     [[TopKV2/_115]]
  (1) Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_2' with dtype float
     [[{{node Placeholder_2}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/media/restore_model.py", line 42, in <module>
    y_prob, y_pred = sess.run(tensor, feed_dict={x:Input_data, keep_prob:1.0, keep_prob_conv:1.0})

  File "/home/user/env/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 950, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)

  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1173, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)

  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1350, in _do_run
    run_metadata)

  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1370, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)

InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_2' with dtype float
     [[node Placeholder_2 (defined at /media/user/env/restore_model.py:26) ]]
     [[TopKV2/_115]]
  (1) Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_2' with dtype float
     [[node Placeholder_2 (defined at /media/user/env/restore_model.py:26) ]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

Are there any ideas why my placeholder argument is invalid, pls share your minds or give me some advises. I have searched answers for this topic but I didn't find the one which can help me.

```
print({x:Input_data, keep_prob:1.0, keep_prob_conv:1.0})
{<tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_4:0' shape=(?, 32, 32, 1) dtype=float32>: array([[[[1.],
         [1.],
         [1.],
         ...,
         [1.],
         [1.],
         [1.]],

        [[1.],
         [1.],
         [1.],
         ...,
         [1.],
         [1.],
         [1.]],

        [[1.],
         [1.],
         [1.],
         ...,
         [1.],
         [1.],
         [1.]],

        ...,

        [[1.],
         [1.],
         [1.],
         ...,
         [1.],
         [1.],
         [1.]],

        [[1.],
         [1.],
         [1.],
         ...,
         [1.],
         [1.],
         [1.]],

        [[1.],
         [1.],
         [1.],
         ...,
         [1.],
         [1.],
         [1.]]],


       [[[1.],
         [1.],
         [1.],
         ...,
         [1.],
         [1.],
         [1.]],

        [[1.],
         [1.],
         [1.],
         ...,
         [1.],
         [1.],
         [1.]],

        [[1.],
         [1.],
         [1.],
         ...,
         [1.],
         [1.],
         [1.]],

        ...,

        [[1.],
         [1.],
         [1.],
         ...,
         [1.],
         [1.],
         [1.]],

        [[1.],
         [1.],
         [1.],
         ...,
         [1.],
         [1.],
         [1.]],

        [[1.],
         [1.],
         [1.],
         ...,
         [1.],
         [1.],
         [1.]]]], dtype=float32), <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_5:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=float32>: 1.0, <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_6:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=float32>: 1.0}
```

Thank you in advance...